# Plotting the solutions to a transcendental equation

Tags: plotting, inverse

I am trying, to no avail, to use *Mathematica* to produce a plot in (x, y)-space of the solutions to the equation

```
Cos[Sqrt[y]] + Sin[Sqrt[y]]/Sqrt[y] == Cos[x]
```

Neither `NSolve` nor `InverseFunction` seem to work for inverting the equation (probably because there are multiple solutions for y for each x). Does anyone know a way to make such a plot?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can plot curves defined by implicit equations using [`ContourPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ContourPlot.html):

```
ContourPlot[
 Cos[Sqrt[y]] + Sin[Sqrt[y]]/Sqrt[y] == Cos[x], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 
  10}]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! this is exactly what I wanted, thank you

Answer (score 5):

Following Jens's answer, if you want the actual values from his implicit plot,

```
tt=ContourPlot[Cos[Sqrt[y]] + Sin[Sqrt[y]]/Sqrt[y] == Cos[x],{x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}];  
data=Cases[tt//Normal, Line[a_] :>  a, Infinity] // First;
ListLinePlot[data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that it need not be a one to one function.

```
tt = ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2 == {1, 2, 3}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}] // Normal;
Cases[tt, Line[a_] :>  a, Infinity]//ListLinePlot[#, AspectRatio -> 1]&
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

Although perhaps less generalizable than the `ContourPlot` solutions, the approach below will work for many similar problems. You will have to guess a reasonable initial value for y, but that should usually not be a problem.

```
Plot[y /. FindRoot[Cos[Sqrt[y]] + Sin[Sqrt[y]]/Sqrt[y] == Cos[x], {y, 1}], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, just showing a nice plot:

```
Show@Table[
   ContourPlot[ Cos[Sqrt[y]] + Sin[Sqrt[y]]/Sqrt[y] == n Cos[x], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 400}],
  {n, 1/4, 5, 1/4}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: just because you felt like it? or is it an April fool in disguise?

Comment: @chris Just because I liked the plot,  and wanted to share it

Answer (score 0):

```
ParametricPlot[{ArcCos[Cos[Sqrt[y]] + Sin[Sqrt[y]]/Sqrt[y]], y}, {y, 1, 2}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 1.6}]
```

[image]